# Impact of adjusting Time of Mongodb server?

Tags: replication, mongodb

Using Ubuntu 14.04 and mongodb 2.6.10

I have time difference between a replica machine and primary , my secondary isn't configured with NTP what are the implications of adjusting time on the secondary machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The impact of time adjustments depends on how significant the clock drift is between members of your replica set. Generally the most impactful outcome will be some confusing diagnostic information: operations during the affected period may appear to have improbably large (or small) durations.

If you are running any multiple server deployment you should always use a clock sync service (eg. NTP) to avoid potential clock drift. Generally services that make small, incremental adjustments to time (eg. `ntpd`) are preferable to utilities that make large adjustments (eg. `ntpdate`).

For more information on the potential outcomes of clock skew with MongoDB, see: [MongoDB and Leap Seconds](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-and-leap-seconds).